# Access response of Jquery autocomplete in change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using Jquery auto complete, So if user searched something and didn't select from auto complete but moved out of text box, then i should select the first in the list automatically. I am trying to do this in change event, but not able to find a way to access the first item in the list. I not only need the text but also value, id other item values too. My question is how can i access the data in change event. Please suggest

```
$("#textbox").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {

       $.ajax({
        url: "GetEmployees", 
        data: "{ 'term': 'test' }",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
         response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
          return {
           value: item.value,
           id: item.id
          }
         }))
        }
       });
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
      },
      change : function(event, ui) {
      }
     });
```